# Javascript to dynamically sort links by presets

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, dynamic

Imagine that I have a directory of links sorted by alphabet, let's say 1000 links. There are lots of links related to different themes.

On top I have buttons, saying ALL, MOBILE, CARS, BOOKS, TECHNOLOGY.

When user clics on MOBILE, he gets the links related to smartphones, tablets, etc. only. When he clicks on BOOKS, he gets links related to books. When he clicks on TECHNOLOGY, he gets the links related to mobiles and cars, but not books. When user clicks on ALL - he gets all links again.

All the relations would be set in advance in some way. It would be good to have it done interactively, like when user clicks on button the not related links would gradually disappear and the related links would move from their previous places to the new list like some sort of animation, like it was done by AJAX.

Now, I hope you see the idea. Is it possible to make this by using jQuery and some plugins, maybe some javascript? Any idea how this could be implemented? Maybe some links to examples, if they exist?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [quick sand plugin](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/). its exactly what you're after

Comment: thank you, http://razorjack.net/quicksand/demos/one-set-clone.html seems to be what I need, but how do I set one item to be related to two or more different "categories"?

Comment: I tried to test that plugin, with 1000 of items to sort it takes long and even makes the script to not respond :(